# Is there a connection between Dr Who "The happiness patrol" and Dr Who "Smile"?

Tags: doctor-who

I was wondering due to in both episodes unhappiness is outlawed and if you are sad you will die, also that I wonder if "Smile" might be a sort of prequel to "The happiness patrol" is this possible as in is there any in canon reports to prove this or am I just making it up?

Answer (score 8):

*Smile* features nanobots which had mistaken grief for a disease and were eliminating it.

*The Happiness Patrol* is set on a colony where sadness had been outlawed by a despotic ruler.

There's no connection beyond the basic concept of *unhappy people die*.